# How does one get about deciphering a cron job really quickly?

Tags: cron

For example */5 * * * * is what ? Is there a reverse calculator?

I know that a cron job is set as :

minute  hour  dayOfMonth  month  dayOfWeek  command

so............what is the /5 mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

/X essentially means 'the ones evenly divisible by X'.  So */5 minutes means 'every five minutes'.  See [the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) for more info.

Also: I think the / syntax might be a vixiecron extension, so it might not be available if  you're working on non-free unices.